# LocalStorage, jquery e CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, localstorage

Estou salvando o tamanho da fonte no `localStorage` e recuperando para setar após a página estar pronta, não estou conseguindo setar usando o valor recuperado no localstorage, para setar  a fonte estou usando jquery, segue código

> ```
> Assim não funciona
> ```

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
// font size
var $elemento = $(".verseTextP");
var fontSize = window.localStorage.getItem('fontSize');
alert(fontSize)
$elemento.css('font-size', fontSize);  
});
```

> ```
> Assim funciona
> ```

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
// font size
var $elemento = $(".verseTextP");
var fontSize = window.localStorage.getItem('fontSize');
alert(fontSize)
$elemento.css('font-size', 25);  
});
```

> O `alert` é pra mostrar que o valor está salvo no `localStorage` e consigo pegar o valor corretamente, qual o problema, porque não funciona se usar o valor vindo de um `locaStorage.getItem`?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está tentando usar o valor do localstorage como um número, acontece que não é garatido isso, você precisa converter, ou adicionar a unidade de medida, caso o valor seja string.

```js
var fontSize = window.localStorage.getItem('fontSize'); 
alert(typeof fontSize); // verifique, deve ser string
$elemento.css('font-size', Number(fontSize));  //aqui garante um número
$elemento.css('font-size', fontSize + "px"); // ou adicione a unidade de medida px,pt,em, etc
```

Comment: Perfeito cara! muito obrigado.